# Filter condition for entity reference field

Tags: views

I am trying to create filter condition for  entity reference field added, but i am unable see the data when i give input in created filter condition text, i am trying from long ago searching in all possible way but dint got the reason please let me know what could be the issue,i will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Views Reference Filter** [Veiw Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) Module for reference fileds.